# Тире или двоеточие в предложениях

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие, уточнения

Ставим ли мы двоеточие или тире в предложениях по типу:

"Как вам писать — на русском или на английском?"
"Какое это предложение — сложносочиненное или сложноподчиненное?"
"Какой вы человек — импульсивный или рассудительный?"

Мне почему-то ближе тире, однако я не могу найти никакого правила, подтверждающего мои догадки. Кажется, что эти части после тире являются уточнениями, так ли это?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, Вы правы — тире в таких предложениях вполне "законный" знак. После тире идут уточнения того, о чём спрашивается в начале.

[**Двоеточие — тире**](http://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=189)

> 6. Параллельное употребление двоеточия и тире встречается при обособлении **пояснительных** и **уточняющих** членов предложения: *Как долго продолжалось это молчание (: —) минуту, три, десять?; Сколько мне тогда было (: —) девятнадцать или двадцать?; Не знаю, когда уехать (: —) в среду или в четверг.*
>
> В заключение можно указать, что в «конкурентной борьбе» двоеточия с тире «победителем» нередко выходит тире. Это явление отмечается многими исследователями, которые считают, что «в целом тире — знак более свободный, заходящий и во владения двоеточия» и что «выявляется тенденция к вытеснению в ряде случаев двоеточия знаком тире».

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ответ, бывает, что у меня возникают трудности с определением уточнений.

Comment: @KingCrimson И вам спасибо!